# Proof of a geometric statement

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

If $D$ is a point inside a triangle  $\triangle ABC$  then how the following statement is true.

**statement:** $AB+AC>BD+DC$.

I have tried in the following way but it seems to me defective.

$$\begin{align}
AB+AC&>BC\tag{1}\\
BD+DC&>BC\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

By subtracting $(1)-(2)$ we get,

$$AB+AC-BD-DC>0$$

or $$AB+AC>BD+DC$$

But if I subtract $(2)-(1)$ we get,

$$BD+DC>AB+AC$$

That is the problem. Can anyone help me to prove the above geometric statement?

Comment: You can't subtract (1) from (2) like that. In negating (2) you need to reverse the inequality from > to <, and you can't add together opposing inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $E$ and $F$ be points on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively such that $DE \parallel AC$ and $DF\parallel BA$.

Answer (score 1):

The two suggestions are not helping since the greater sum segments may each be smaller than one of the segments in the smaller sum. The same way it is quite easy to create a case in which angel DAB is acute.
Here is a solution:
[image]

Comment: Don’t understand “the greater sum segments may each be smaller than one of the segments in the smaller sum”. An example acting as illustration would be nice. Another thing is:- If you think that other person’s suggested solution is NOT “helping”, that person should have the right of being informed.

Comment: @Mick Here is some clarification: In a triangle the sum of two sides is always greater than the third side. The third side may be still larger than each of the two sides. I am just writing two inequality related to the triangles DEC and ABE. Summing the two larger sums maintains the inequality so they are greater than the sum of the smaller ones. I just used different triangles to create the useful sums.

Comment: Your proof seems to be all right and I have nothing to say against it. The things that I would like to point out are (1) why is that my suggestion is “not helping”? (2) if you did make such a claim, you have the courtesy to inform the owner of that suggestion so that he/she has a chance to defend him/her self.

Comment: @Mick There are many ways to prove things in math/geometry. Hints that require elaborate involvement might cause more confusion than help. Since there was a much simpler (I think) and straight forward way that leads to an answer, a hint could distract. I think that this is the case here. Some individuals are not interested in getting deeply in reasons but I hope that you understand now why I think your hint might be confusing to a simple solution. I think that a good hint for this one would be: Extend BD to intersect AC at E. Since the guy did some work - thought I better provide a solution.

Comment: Your criticism in the answer was only applicable to a third answer which has now been deleted. Mick's hint is perfectly fine – he relies on the same famous inequality that you do. Since your criticism is now fully obsolete, please remove it. Please also remove the last sentence (no one is going to add extra steps to your answer), and move the text/math out of the image (see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for how to format math on this site). While your answer to the question itself is correct, the surrounding noise prevents me from upvoting your post in good conscience.

Comment: @epimorphic Thanx 4 the help.