# Question involving area and perimeter of two parallelograms sharing a diagonal.

Tags: geometry, puzzle, area

Given two parallelograms $P1$ and $P2$ sharing a diagonal, such that area of $P1$ is greater than area of $P2$, can we say that the perimeter of $P1$ is greater than the perimeter of $P2$ ? 
Actually I was trying to prove another question : [Proof of a geometric statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168813/proof-of-a-geometric-statement/1169360#1169360) 
I thought of using this argument as shown in the following picture . Here $1$ represents parallelogram with sides $AB$ and $AC$ and $2$ represents area of parallelogram with sides $BD$ and $CD$.[image: My attempt] :

Comment: I'm only looking at parallelograms where one is inside the other and they share a doagonal. Can you give an answer keeping the diagram in mind ? I need this only as a way to prove another statement.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I will have to think. Can we use trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not comment -
Your question boils down to a simpler claim:
The perimeter of a triangle created by connecting a point in a scalene and acute  triangle to any two vertices, is smaller than the original triangle perimeter.

I tested this with Geogebra - and it seems correct.  The comment made by Sawarnik is not relevant to your claim - which is true but require proof.

I provided a proof on your first post, that the parallelogram that contains the smaller one has a larger perimeter.

You may accept the answers on both posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two parallelograms:

(-2,0),(0,1.01),(2,0),(0,-1.01)

(-2,0),(-2,1),(2,0),(2,-1)